# Segmentation fault when loading words from txt file to a trie, if last line is empty

Tags: c, cs50

UPDATED (see below)

I work on a CS50 problem set to load a dictionary of words from a text file to a trie structure. My code results in either:

1) segmentation fault, when last line of the text file is empty, like:

1. cat
2. zoo
3. zoom
4. rite
5. 

or 2) last word is not loaded to the trie, when it's the last line of the text file:

1. cat
2. zoo
3. zoom
4. rite

Here is the code I use to load the words to the trie:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "dictionary.h"

// declaring trie structure
typedef struct trie
{
    bool is_word;
    struct trie* letters[27];
} trie;

//root node
trie* head; 

//global variable will be used to count words loaded into trie
int words;

/**
 * Loads dictionary into memory.  Returns true if successful else false.
 */
bool load(const char* dictionary)
{

    // set global words variable to 0 before the count starts
    words = 0;

    //declaring first node of the trie and pointing in to NULL
    head = (struct trie*)malloc(sizeof(trie));

    //set all root node pointers to null
    for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++)
    {
        head->letters[i] = NULL;
    }

    // open dictionary file 
    FILE* inptr = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (inptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open %s.\n", dictionary);
        return 2;
    }

    //declare new trie to jump thru characters
    trie* current = head;

    //go thru each character in the file until end of file 
    for (int i = 0, ch = 1; ch != EOF; i++)
    {
        //read the current character from file
        ch = fgetc(inptr);

        // if the character is a letter or an apostrophe 
        if (ch != '\n')
        {
            //if the pointer for the character doesn't exist (equals NULL) allocate memory
            if (current->letters[tolower(ch) - 'a'] == NULL)
            {
                current->letters[tolower(ch) - 'a'] = (struct trie*)malloc(sizeof(trie));
            }
            //move forward in our trie structure
            current = current->letters[tolower(ch) - 'a'];
        } 

        //if the character read indicates the end of the line
        else 
        {
            //indicate that this is a word in our dictionary in the trie
            current->is_word = true;
            //reset our current node to the beginning of the trie
            current = head;
            //count number of words loaded in the dictionary
            words++;
        }
    }

    printf ("%i words loaded to the dictionary\n", words);

    // close infile
    fclose(inptr);

    return true;
}
```

I guess the issue is with the way EOF and fgetc != '\n' conditions are used.

How can I indicate to the trie that is the word ends with EOF it's still a word AND avoid the seg fault, if EOF is on a new line?

**UPDATE**

Trying it with a while loop instead (here below). Finally don't have a seg fault in the case (1) as described above. But the last word is not written into the trie regardless of whether the last line is empty or not.
Plus, the very first letter of the first word is not written since there's a double call to fgetc function at the beginning of the loop.

Will continue to work with the debugger and the loop declaration. I'm welcoming more suggestions.

```
//go thru each character in the file until end of file 
while((ch = fgetc(inptr)) != EOF) 
{
    //read the current character from file
    ch = fgetc(inptr);

    // if the character is a letter or an apostrophe 
    if (ch != '\n')
    {
        //if the pointer for the character doesn't exist (equals NULL) allocate memory
        if (current->letters[tolower(ch) - 'a'] == NULL)
        {
            current->letters[tolower(ch) - 'a'] = (struct trie*)malloc(sizeof(trie));
        }
        //move forward in our trie structure
        current = current->letters[tolower(ch) - 'a'];
    } 

    //if the character read indicates the end of the line
    else 
    {
        //indicate that this is a word in our dictionary in the trie
        current->is_word = true;
        //reset our current node to the beginning of the trie
        current = head;
        //count number of words loaded in the dictionary
        words++;
    }
}
```

P.S. I'm still learning, don't judge me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: You should first read and then check for eof. Not the other way around as you  do in your loop...

Comment: Thanks, @PaulR. The thing is I used the debugger on this program, and it doesn't complain about seg faults. So I'm not sure where the problem happens.

Comment: One thing to keep it mind is that `malloc` does not initialize memory. If you rely on empty trie child pointers being `NULL`, you need to initialize the structure yourself (I'm referring in the second call of `malloc`).

Comment: You are testing for `EOF` in the wrong place, and the `for`  loop does not use the `i`. I suggest replacing those few lines with `int ch; while((ch = fgetc(inptr)) != EOF ) { if (ch != '\n') ... }`

Comment: *So I'm not sure where the problem happens* - learn to use valgrind, it should help.

Comment: `return 2;` The function was defined as returning `bool`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Ok, so this declaration is faulty: for (int i = 0, ch = 1; ch != EOF; i++), specifically the ch != EOF. Then I should put the if condition on ch = EOF inside the loop itself. I see some suggestion on replacing the for loop with a while

Comment: @WeatherVane, won't the loop condition advance the cursor prematurely and skip the first character?

Comment: @kfx, this part of code is being stored in a library and is called upon by a different program, it doesn't have a main function, so valgrind can be executed only on the main program, and shows that all is good (I hope this lengthy explanation makes sense).

Comment: Your favorite debugger is your friend.

Comment: You could replace `if (ch != '\n')` with `if (ch != '\n' && ch != EOF)`, which should work even if the newline is missing at the end of the file.

Comment: @D.B. no the first character will not be skipped. You can easily check out things like this with a bit of gash code that prints out the known contents of a small file. Once you have successfully extracted all (and only) the words in the file, then you can think about the trie.

Comment: Re your update: remove the second line of the `while` loop `ch = fgetc(inptr);` entirely. Its functionality has moved into the `while` statement, and is causing *two* characters to be read in each iteration.

Comment: From your code, it seems the input file strictly contains single words per line. Are you not allowed to read words?

Comment: @alvits, yes, the file has 1 word per line. I can also read words, but need to use either a trie or a hash structure to load the dictionary. I went with the trie where I store 1 character in each node at a time.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to the great help and support from the community, I have fixed the code and it now works as excepted. The loop is now as follows:

```
    //go thru each character in the file until end of file 
    while((ch = fgetc(inptr)) != EOF) 
    {

        // if the character is a letter or an apostrophe 
        if (ch != '\n')
        {
            //if the pointer for the character doesn't exist (equals NULL) allocate memory
            if (current->letters[tolower(ch) - 'a'] == NULL)
            {
                current->letters[tolower(ch) - 'a'] = (struct trie*)malloc(sizeof(trie));
            }
            //move forward in our trie structure
                current = current->letters[tolower(ch) - 'a'];
        } 

        //if the character read indicates the end of the line
        else 
        {
            //indicate that this is a word in our dictionary in the trie
            current->is_word = true;
            //reset our current node to the beginning of the trie
            current = head;
            //count number of words loaded in the dictionary
            words++;
        }
    }
```